# Angular Routes with URL Parameters Not working when Deployed in GoogleAppEngine/AWS S3 , but works perfect in LocalHost/LocalIP

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

This is First time i developed a full fledged application with Angular , I deployed it in both Google App Engine / AWS Free Tier.
In Back End it's running on Spring Boot Rest API deployed in AWS.
App loads fine with root domain
http://feedtalk.in (Click to Open)

But no URL with parameter is opening 
http://feedtalk.in/article/maruti-suzuki-ignis-limited-edition-to-be-launched-soon

But all works fine locally , localhost:4200/127.0.0.0:4200/192.168.1.5:4200(wifi-router)
all works fine.

app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ArticlereaderComponent } from './articlereader/articlereader.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { EscapeHtmlPipe } from './pipes/keep-html.pipe';
    import { LinksreaderComponent } from './linksreader/linksreader.component';
    import { SearchfeedsComponent } from './searchfeeds/searchfeeds.component';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { CommentmanagerComponent } from './commentmanager/commentmanager.component';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'article/:urlLink', component: ArticlereaderComponent,
        children: [{ path: 'comments/:commentjson', component: CommentmanagerComponent }]

      },
      { path: 'newslinks/:urlLink', component: LinksreaderComponent },
      { path: 'search/:query', component: SearchfeedsComponent },
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ArticlereaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    EscapeHtmlPipe,
    LinksreaderComponent,
    SearchfeedsComponent,
    CommentmanagerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true }, // <-- debugging purposes only
    )

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
declare var $: any;
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public router: Router) {
    this.getTopStories();
    this.getAllStories();
    this.getMostRead();
    this.getLatestNewsLinks("TOPSTORY");

  }
  public forwardURL(urlLink: string) {
    window.open("article/" + urlLink, "_self");
  }
  public forwardlLink(urlLink:string){ 
    window.open("newslinks/" + urlLink, "_self");
  }
```

app.component.html

```
 <div class="list-group" *ngFor="let Feed of AllStories" (click)="forwardURL(Feed.urlLink)">
```

articlereader.component.ts

```
export class ArticlereaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public feed: Feed;
  public nextFeed: Feed;
  public tags: any;
  public parameterLink: any;
  public MostRead;
  public NonPolitics;
  public RelatedArticle;
  public Comments;
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, public http: HttpClient, public router: Router) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.parameterLink = params.urlLink;
    });
    this.getArticle();
    this.getMostRead();
    this.getNonPoliticsFeeds();

  }
  public forwardURL(urlLink: string) {
    window.open("article/" + urlLink, "_self");
  }
  public getArticle() {
    this.http.get(AppComponent.APIHost + "/feed/FeedByUrl/" + this.parameterLink + "/").subscribe(data => {
      this.feed = data;
      this.Comments = this.feed.comments;
      this.tagsSplit();
      this.getNextfeed(this.feed["feedId"]);
      this.getRelated(this.feed["feedId"]);
    });

  }
```

Comment: You'll probably need to configure URL rewriting or something. Also, you need to to set `base href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your S3 bucket set the error document to index.html as well as your index document.